# How to render taxonomy in loop of custom post_type

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy

I made custom post type and taxonomy 
and on my page template I want to render the taxonomy name in my css class. Anyone know how to render it?

This is what I have so far

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
          $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio' );
          //debugging array
          echo '<pre>';
          print_r($terms);
          echo '</pre>';
          echo "<a href='" .get_the_permalink() . "'><figure class='". $terms->name ."'>";
          the_post_thumbnail();
          echo "</figure></a>";
        endwhile;
    ?>
```

And as results:

```
Array
(
    [200] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 200
            [name] => Plugins
            [slug] => plugins
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 200
            [taxonomy] => portfolio
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [object_id] => 1776
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

I tried calling it like:

```
$terms->name;
```

But I get this as info in wp:

```
Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in....
```

Comment: you will need to loop through the terms array (foreach $terms as $term)

Comment: Oh yeah great, silly me..

       foreach ($terms as $term) {
                echo $term->name;
              }

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
   echo $term->name; 
   echo $term->slug;

   ...
   ... 
}
```